# JPA @Column does not work for column name with special character

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a column with name like `ac-bnm_kj`.

I have defined the attribute in the entity class as:

```java
@Column("ac-bnm_kj")
String acbnm;
```

But this config is giving me the following error:

```
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

because the query is generating with name `ac-bnm_kj` which is invalid.
How can I wrap double quotes around this column name when the query is being generated like `ac-bnm_kj`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [backticks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers):

```java
@Column("`ac-bnm_kj`")
String acbnm;
```

or JPA style quoting

```java
@Column("\"ac-bnm_kj\"")
String acbnm;
```